# merge two columns

Tags: merge, sed, grep, while-loop, paste

input_file

```
A B C D;X;Y 0
C D E F;Z;X 1
```

Output_file

```
A B C D;X;Y;0
C D E F;Z;X;1
```

I would like to merge the last column of input_file with the second last column and separate the value of last column with ";" in second last column(just like in column number 4 of input_file). hence that output_file has one less column. There is no distinct pattern for each line so that I can use grep, but i can use "while read line" but don't know how to apply sed for the last column entry in each line.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Append the last value onto the 2nd-last value, and then remove the last value:

```
awk '{$(NF-1) = $(NF-1) ";" $NF; NF--} 1'
```

Or, treat the file as semi-colon separated and split the last column

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = OFS = ";"} {gsub(/[[:space:]]+/, FS, $NF)} 1'
```

Comment: Thanks the second option is working fine, first option is changing the format, as my input file is tab delimited and when I'm running first option the the output file is no longer tab delimited.As I aslo need to add a "specific tag" with each value in the last column. Ex. output file:

Comment: @glenn jackman Using second option (as it keeps the formatting in output), Could you please also tell me how to add a "specific tag" with each value in the last column and then merging tag with value to the second last column. Ex.outputfile:                                                      A B C D;X;Y;Apple=0
C D E F;Z;X;Apple=1

Comment: For the first option, if it's specifically tab-delimited, use `awk -F '\t' -v 'OFS="\t"' '...' file`

Comment: You just need to alter the last column: `awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=";"} {gsub(...); $NF = "Apple=" $NF}; 1'`

Comment: @glen jackman thanks...but  awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=";"} {gsub(...); $NF = "Apple=" $NF}; 1' is adding tag "apple" to the last value of 4th column and then merging the 5th column to it...so output is        A B C D;X;apple=Y;0 and not A B C D;X;Y;apple=0, as there are SPACES in column four values D;<>X;<>Y; (sorry for not mentioning earlier)

Comment: This is getting pretty complicated without proper formatting. Please ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{$NF=";"$NF;print}' input_file>output_file
```

Comment: thanks ..it worked but just a query.... does $NF cause any differences for 'space delimited' files and 'tab delimited' files? sorry for not mentioning before, my input file is tab delimited.

Comment: @Ank If it worked, you may want to choose Peter's answer as the right answer.

Comment: @steve the output file is no longer in tab delimited format.please help to keep the formatting.thanks

Comment: @sarathi the output file is no more tab delimited, how to keep the formatting intact.thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 's/ \(.\)$/;\1/' input_file > output_file
```

or if your last column may have several characters

```
sed -e 's/ \([[:alnum:]]*\)$/;\1/' input_file > output_file
```